# Laravel Nayjest datagrid Stored procedure mapping

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, laravel-5, datagrid

I am trying to use Nayjest datagrid for showing MySql dynamic stored procedure results.

Here is the MySql stored procedure sample code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`Dummy`@`%` PROCEDURE `get_contacts`(
  orderColumns VARCHAR(21844) CHARACTER SET utf8, 
  whereColumns VARCHAR(21844) CHARACTER SET utf8,
  likeColumns VARCHAR(21844) CHARACTER SET utf8
)
BEGIN
   ...
   PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_txt;
   EXECUTE stmt;
   DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Here is the Laravel code:

```
$cfg = [
        //'src' => DB::select('CALL get_contacts(null, null, null);')//'App\Models\Clients',
        'columns' => [
            'idClients',
            'Nom',
            'Prenom',
            'Adresse'
        ]
    ];
    $grid = Grids::make($cfg);
    $query = DB::select('CALL get_contacts(null, null, null);');
    $grid = $grid->setDataProvider($query);
```

In final version, columns name will be generated in the flow.

**Error message:**

> LogicException in BuildDataProvider.php line 57:
>   Invalid Data Provider Configuration

Seems it works only with `EloquentServiceProvider`.

Any help?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: What is the working version using Eloquent? I'm guessing you are calling `get()` or `all()` when using Eloquent, which returns a Collection, whereas your `DB::select()` is returning a query builder instance.

Comment: get() is doing the same error "LogicException in BuildDataProvider.php line 57:
Invalid Data Provider Configuration"

Comment: Looking at the docs, I don't think it supports non-Eloquent queries.

Comment: Seems https://github.com/view-components/grids is the solution